Superconductors and XY model
At (near) zero temperature, one usually studies superconductors (SC) via BCS theory (i.e., the variational Hamiltonian approach), while at finite temperatures, SCs are modeled as a classical XY model due to the fact that the nature of SC is $U(1)$ symmetry breaking (charge not conserved).
I feel like the connection between finite temperature classical XY model and zero temperature BCS theory is not very apparent (despite being well-recognized). For example, it would be much more apparent that the quantum version of a classical XY model would be the Heisenberg model but restricted to the XY plane, e.g., interactions of the form $XX+YY$.
In any case, what is a more apparent way of showing quantum (zero temperature) effects of a classical XY model? So that at finite temperature, the quantum model "reduces" in some sense to the classical XY model.
EDIT. After some research, here is an example of a possible quantum spin model that reduces to the classical XY model in some limit (whether this model is the correct zero temperature limit is not certain).
Consider
$$
H = -\sum_{\langle ij\rangle} b_i^\dagger b_j +U\sum_{i}(b_i^\dagger b_i-\mu)^2
$$
Where $b$ are bosonic (annhilation) operators. Note that $H$ is globally $U(1)$ invariant, i.e., $b_i^\dagger \mapsto e^{i\phi} b_i^\dagger$ for all $i$. To emphasize this, one can rewrite the operators $b^\dagger_i = e^{i \phi_i} n_i$ where $n_i = b_i^\dagger b_i$ using polar decomposition. Note that $n,\phi$ satisfy the nontrivial conjugate relations $[n,\phi]= i$, which derive from the commutation relations of $b^\dagger,b$.
Of course, even rewriting the $H$ in variables $\phi,n$ doesn't quite give you the right Hamiltonian, so instead, let me use the derived commutation relation $[n,\phi]=i$ and define the modified Hamiltonian
$$
H_\text{mod} = -\sum_{\langle ij\rangle} \cos (\phi_i-\phi_j) +U\sum_i(n_i-\mu)^2
$$
This modified Hamiltonian would then reduce to the classical XY model in the scenario of $U=0$, but would have quantum effects when $U>0$.

But that "classical" XY spin is not a spin.  It is the U(1) phase of the order parameter, already a purely quantum object.

As in, even if you go to zero temperature, you still have a "classical spin" that can point along any angle.  The keyword you are looking for is the non-linear sigma model.

Morally, that's true, but technically, shouldn't a quantum spin model also be capable of possessing $U(1)$ symmetry. Of course, a classical system is easier to study, so for all intents and practical purposes, it's understandable to study the classical XY model, but let's say I want a quantum spin model since superconductivity is a quantum effect.

"shouldn't a quantum spin model also be capable of possessing U(1)
symmetry":  NO.  Different representation.  And as I said, the U(1) phase is no less quantum than, says, spin-1/2.

I'm not sure if I agree. Indeed, the Heisenberg model possesses $SO(3)$ symmetry due to $XX+YY+ZZ$ interaction, but if we limit to $XX+YY$ interaction, then it's clear that the system possesses $U(1)$ symmetry. Now I'm not sure if that's the "correct" $U(1)$ symmetry, but it at leasts possesses $U(1)$ symmetry

We are talking about the quantum theory of a compactified bosonic degree of freedom.  The Hilbert space is the infinite tower of angular momentum states, labeled by integers.  It can't fit into any spin model.  You need to cook up some $J\rightarrow\infty$ limit at least.

"Classical" unfortunately is used (abused?) to imply more than one things.  In this specific instance, it only means the assumption of dropping (imaginary) time dependence.
